# How to add a form validation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have 3 fields which I want to validate

```
<form name='Login' method='post' target='_self'>
      <div class="loginPic"...>
         <input id="accountLoginField" class="loginEmail" type="text" name="account" value="" placeholder="">
         <input id="userLoginField" class="loginUsername" type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="">
         <input id="passLoginField" class="loginPassword" type="password" name="password" value=""
                           placeholder=""> ....
```

And I have submit input

```
<input id="btn_login" type="submit" name="submit" class="buttonM bBlue" value="Connect">
```

How can I check if these fields are empty and show alert box?
I tried diferent ways that I found here and on other sites, but none of them seems to work... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate using if and else and check with the **values** attribute like, this the sample code you can refer for,

```
        function validateform(){  
var name=document.myform.name.value;  
var password=document.myform.password.value;  
  
if (name==null || name==""){  
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}else if(password.length<6){  
  alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
  return false;  
  }  
}  
</script>  
<body>  
<form name="myform" method="post" action="abc.jsp" onsubmit="return validateform()" >  
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>  
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register">  
</form>
```

Likewise, you can check for every field.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will submit to a live test server and the response will be displayed in an `<iframe>` for demonstration purposes. Client side validation is minimal and of course the server should do the heavy lifting when it comes to validation. Here are the major points:

1. Make sure the submit button is within the `<form>`. If for some reason it isn't, add `form="*"` to it (`"*"` is the id of `<form>`). Although it's totally valid for `<form>` to have a `name`, an `id` is more useful so in example `<form id='login'...>`.
2. Each field has a `required` attribute so it can be validated when the "submit" event is triggered, the first blank `<input>` will have a popup.
3. The first `<input>` `type` has been changed to `"email"` so validation will stop submission should the user forget `@`.

```html
<form id='login' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='POST' target='response'>
  <fieldset>
    <input name="account" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input name="user" type="text" placeholder='User name' required>
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Connect">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<label>These two buttons are outside of form.</label><br>
<input type='submit' form='login' value='Works'>
<input type='submit' value="Doesn't Work"><br>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```